# What are the best options for achieving SQL Server - SFDC integration in real time?

Tags: integration, sqlserver

We have a need where we need to create a real time integration from SQL server to salesforce like a message queue.

Whenever a record is inserted or updated on a sql server table, we want the data to be posted in realtime to salesforce using the api.

Here are some options which we are considering and we want to know if you guys have encountered this scenario.

1. We want to know if we can create an external data-source in salesforce using lightning connect  which can connect to a web-service which would feed the data to salesforce. Do standard web-services in .NET are compliant with odata format and can we do this?
2. Is there any way we can create a messaging service where sql server can post data using SSIS as a request and can salesforce to the service and update automatically?

Please feel free to share your thoughts on how you do real time integration from sql server to salesforce at the moment?

Thanks
Buyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely use lightning connect for your requirement .

I did a small POC with help of windows azure website to host a OData webservice .

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2015/01/lightning-connect-and-sql-integration_3.html

Also I posted small demo video for same

https://www.youtube.com/watch?x-yt-ts=1421914688&x-yt-cl=84503534&v=Jz6DAhiKpmU

Answer (score 2):

My opinion - and this is an opinion question - is that you should use DBAmp: http://www.forceamp.com/

I've used it before, it works great, and it's fairly cheap.

(I am not affiliated with this company and do not receive anything in return for recommending them.)

Comment: I agree with John and if you want real-time you can use the OPENQUERY feature of DBAmp where you can query directly to Salesforce. The only disadvantage is that you use APIs and you should do bulk queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want messaging capabilities you should use Streaming APIs and create Push Topics. The resources for that is here https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API.

If you want .NET integration just google Force.com Toolkit .NET. You could also install it via NuGet so any versions in the future they will be automatically delivered to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to originate requests with the database, I'd suggest using [SQL Server Service Broker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), which is a built-in message queue.  It's quick, trackable and reliable.